# Javascript Query.setQuery() to Google sheets using the Google visualization API gives 'Missing query for request id: undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-sheets

I'm using the JavaScript Google visualization API to query tables of a spreadsheet. This works fine if I don't specify a specific query (or use 'select *'), but on using Query.setQuery('select ...') the requestId seems to get lost:

> Uncaught Error: Missing query for request id: undefined

Code:

```
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(queryTable);

function queryTable() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/129uqCEZksVwOSlqTYF7HVrnbOqD3HqPq-warEMvdur8/edit#gid=0');
    query.setQuery('select Date, Time, Name, Type, Preference'); // remove this line and it works
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}


function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
       alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
       return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
    var numrows = data.getNumberOfRows();
    var tableHtml = '<table width="320">';

    for (var row=0; row < numrows; row++) {

        var date = data.getValue(row, 0);
        var time = data.getValue(row, 1);
        var name = data.getValue(row, 2);
        var type = data.getValue(row, 3);
        var pref = data.getValue(row, 4);

        tableHtml += '<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + type + '</td><td>' + pref + '</td>';
    }
    tableHtml += '</table>';
    $('#table').append(tableHtml);
}
```

The test spreadsheet is viewable here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/129uqCEZksVwOSlqTYF7HVrnbOqD3HqPq-warEMvdur8/edit?usp=sharing

Sorry if this is a Noob question but can't seem to find a solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is invalid, you use the column-labels, but you must use the column-identifiers:

```
query.setQuery("select A,B,C,D,E ");
```